# ZUUIRevealController revealToggle method calling?

Tags: iphone

I am using ZUUIRevealViewController. Does someone know how to call revealToggle method from a button contained in the view of my frontviewcontroller and not from the navigation bar button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call:

```
[self.navigationController.parentViewController revealToggle:nil];
```

**EDIT:**

You need to cast

```
[(ZUUIRevealController *)self.navigationController.parentViewController revealToggle:nil];
```

Comment: Actually there does not exist any method named revealToggle on the instance of self.navigationController.parentViewController. That`s the prob. So I need to figure on which object instance do I need to call this method

Comment: You have to cast it to (ZUUIRevealController *) look at my edit

Comment: Thanks Shabzco. It works perfectly. Now suppose I have to go back to my FrontViewController from RearViewController, then how will Call the same method from my RearViewController.

Comment: Got it. This is how the method needs to be called.       `RevealController *revealController = [self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[RevealController class]] ? (RevealController *)self.parentViewController : nil;`
    [revealController revealToggle:self];